# How to get dates to filter into specific columns, without duplicating rows. Possible without Union?

Tags: sql

Creating results that filter dates into two columns (we'll call them 30 day adn 60 day). The column that needs to be filled is based on another column. I'm trying to get these columns to fill without having to union (if it's even possible)

Let's say that you get a letter on day 30 and a different letter on day 60. I want the results to look like this

```
User   30 day Letter Date     60 Day Letter Date
TIM     2021-02-01            2021-03-03
```

Currently, the query is taking the above and splitting it into 2 separate rows where the 30/60 day column will be NULL when applicable and filling in the correct date. In order to get that I'm running the following

```
Select c.name as User,
CASE WHEN letter_id = '123' then letter.created ELSE NULL End as '30 day letter',
CASE WHEN letter_id = '456' then letter.created ELSE NULL End as '60 day letter'
From customer c
inner join letter l on c.id=l.customer_id
where letter_id IN ('123','456')
```

Again, I can get results with 2 rows but just wondering if it's possible to get 1 row without a union but still have items filter to the right place.

Comment: I recommend tagging your RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want aggregation:

```
Select c.name as User,
       max(CASE WHEN l.letter_id = '123' then l.created End) as letter_30_day,
       max(CASE WHEN l.letter_id = '456' then l.created End) as letter_60_day
From customer c inner join
     letter l
     on c.id = l.customer_id
where letter_id IN ('123', '456')
group by c.name;
```

Comment: Aggregation put me on the correct path. A couple of tweaks and I got to where I needed to be. Thanks for being the Spark